# 2 Excel VBS Script Calling Multiple Macros causes a macro cannot be found or macros are disabled on second script

Tags: excel, vba

I have a two vbs scripts that are calling macros in the same workbook.   I had to split them out due to the script would move onto the next macro before completing.  The issue that  I am experiencing is once the batch file calls the next script, I get an error that the macro is not in the workbook.  Since the excel spreadsheet is still open I tried to use a getobject in the script.  See below for the first script and next script.
#1

```
'Input Excel File's Full Path
  ExcelFilePath = "\\file path"

'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File
  MacroPath = "Module2.Todays_Date"   'macro #1

'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File
  MacroPath5 = "Module2.RefreshBBG"   'macro #2

'Create an instance of Excel
  Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do you want this Excel instance to be visible?
  ExcelApp.Visible = True  

'Prevent any App Launch Alerts (ie Update External Links)
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open Excel File
  Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

'Execute Macro Code
  'ExcelApp.Run MacroPath

'Execute Macro Code
  'ExcelApp.Run MacroPath5

Script #2  (Excel is still open from the previous script)
'Input Excel File's Full Path
  ExcelFilePath = "\\file path"

'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File
  MacroPath3 = "Module1.SaveAsTSV"

'Create an instance of Excel (My thought is this isnt needed since excel is open already)
   'Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do you want this Excel instance to be visible?
  'ExcelApp.Visible = True  

'Prevent any App Launch Alerts (ie Update External Links)
 'ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open Excel File (thought is this would activate the workbook)
  Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.GetObject(ExcelFilePath)

'Execute Macro Code
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath3

'Save Excel File (if applicable)
 wb.Save

'Close Excel File
  wb.Close

'Leaves an onscreen message!
  MsgBox "Your Automated Task successfully ran at " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation

'End instance of Excel
  ExcelApp.Quit
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a good idea to include the workbook name in the argument passed to `Application.Run`   E.g.   `Application.Run "'" & wbName & "'!Module2.Todays_Date"`

Comment: Are you suggesting to replace i.e. ExcelApp.Run MacroPath3 for Application.Run " ' " & 1 - APX Pricing Template.Name & " ' Module1.SaveAsTSV"

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to include the workbook name in the argument passed to `Application.Run`

E.g.

```vb
ExcelFilePath = "\\file path\myFile.xlsm" 'Input Excel File's Full Path

Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Visible = True
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

ExcelApp.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!Module2.Todays_Date"
ExcelApp.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!Module2.RefreshBBG"
```

Not clear on why you have 2 scripts - `Application.Run` should block until the macro you call has completed its run.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a shot.  The reason I have two scripts is due to the fact that it is an excel widget that does a background task and updates a number of prices.   In my batch I have a timeout that gives it enough time to update the prices.  The second script simply calls another macro that exports out the file and saves it in another format for import.  I tried a number of different vba functions that I hoped would let the process finish like CalculationState. xldone but it seemed like it was ignored.

Comment: I tried this and still no luck.   The issue is the second batch since the workbook is still open from the previous script it causes a second workbook to open.  I changed the .Open to .Activate but I get an error.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.  As I mentioned earlier that the first script opens the workbook which brings in a ton of data and the second script calls the macro to save the file in a certain format to import.  Thanks